# Redirecting to Specific Page after Language Selection with GTranslate Plugin

Tags: redirect, translation

Dear WordPress StackExchange Community,

I have been using the GTranslate plugin, and I'm thrilled with its functionality. However, I am facing a challenge and would appreciate your insights.

Here's the scenario: I've added the GTranslate shortcode to a blank page. When a visitor selects a language, the translation occurs successfully, but the buttons act as dead links, keeping the visitor on the same page. My goal is to redirect them to a different page upon selecting a language.

Could you please guide me on how to achieve this redirection after a language is selected using the GTranslate plugin?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Best regards,

Comment: You'll have to ask GTranslate's support team about this; third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.